# Erasing my data on the txt file while trying to add numbers in Java

Tags: java, file, file-writing

The following code works fine except the code that is supposed to add numbers to an existing txt file (`Fred56.txt`). He posted the:

```
PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(file);
outputfile.println(totalDeposit);
outputfile.close();
```

I tried to search for it but I cannot find the correct answer when it comes to ask the user the (Scanner) file name. I would like to add the `totalDeposit` to the existing datas on the file witout erasing them.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSavingsAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        double totalDeposit = 0;
        double totalInterest = 0 ;
        double totalWithdraw = 0;
        String filename ;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the annual interest rate");
        double userAnnualinterest = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(" Enter the starting balance");
        double userStartingbalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(" Enter the number of months");
        int userNumberMonths = keyboard.nextInt();

        SavingsAccount account1 = new SavingsAccount(userStartingbalance);
        account1.setAnnualInterest(userAnnualinterest);

        for(int currentmonth = 1 ; currentmonth <= userNumberMonths; currentmonth ++ )
        {
            System.out.println("How much did you deposit during the month ?" + currentmonth);
            double depositAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();

            account1.deposit(depositAmount);
            totalDeposit += depositAmount ;

            System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw ?" + currentmonth);
            double userWithdraw = keyboard.nextDouble();
            account1.withdraw(userWithdraw);
            totalWithdraw += userWithdraw ;

            totalInterest += account1.addMonthlyInterest();


            keyboard.nextLine() ;

            System.out.println(" What is the file name ?");
            filename = keyboard.nextLine() ;
            File file = new File(filename);

            PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(file);
            outputfile.println(totalDeposit);
            outputfile.close();

        }

        System.out.println(" The final balance of the end " + userNumberMonths + "is" +
            account1.getBalance() + " total amount of withdraw " + totalWithdraw +
            " Total amount of deposit " +totalDeposit + " The total of interest" + totalInterest);

    }

}
```

Comment: I did that but it stills erase the previous data. {
   keyboard.nextLine() ;
   
   System.out.println(" What is the file name ?");
       filename = keyboard.nextLine() ;
       File file = new File(filename);
       
       PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(file);
    outputfile.println(totalDeposit);
    outputfile.close();
       
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you are asking for a solution to open a file in append mode.
There are several ways to achieve that. You can use the following in code.

```
try{
   PrintWriter outputfile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter (filename, true)));
   outputfile.println(totalDeposit);
   outputfile.close();
   }catch(IOException ex){
// Handle your exception
   }
```

Comment: That object construction is triggering

Comment: Thank you very much . It has solved my problem !. I am wondering with the book Starting out Java has given that savingsAccount problem then asked to add the deposits to an existing file without studying the try and catch features ?

Comment: Do you think that's the only way to solve the issue ? I tried to run the existing code outside the loop and it did not worked.

Comment: @Freddy53 No, that is not the only way. You can look for different ways to open a file in append mode. Try to read the exception message 'ex'  in the catch block. It will give you the error you getting in different scenarios.

Comment: I have searched the web and in fact that you need the code you wrote about. I did not find other ways to do it. Weird that Gaddis is asking us to find that solution without even  talked about catch and try in his previous chapters.